# How to get the latitude and longitude values for an Airbnb listing via web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, coordinates

I am trying to obtain the latitude and the longitude of the listings that appear in Airbnb, I think that the information is in embedded google map. When I tried to scrape that object by copying the full Xpath with lxml library or with Beautiful Soup, and I cannot get it. For example the listing https://www.airbnb.co.uk/rooms/15307317, has the information of longitude and latitude in the center of the map in an object with tag div img with attribute data-veloute = "map/GoogleMapStatic", I tried to use the link that starts with https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center= but I could not identify the correct object with my code.

```
url = 'https://www.airbnb.co.uk/rooms/15307317'
response = http.request('GET', url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data, 'lxml')
soup.find("div", {"data-veloute":"map/GoogleMapStatic"})
soup.find("img", {"data-veloute":"map/GoogleMapStatic"})
```

or with the next code:

```
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
tree = html.fromstring(resp.content)
tree.xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div/main/div/section/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[10]/div/div/div/div/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/img')
```

Is there any possibility of getting this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As RafalS suggested, you should use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) or another browser scripting lib.

Here's what I came up with.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.parse as urlparse
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

def main():
    chrome_options = Options()  
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  #if you don't want the GUI to pop up
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver.get('https://www.airbnb.co.uk/rooms/15307317')
    time.sleep(2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
    url = (soup.find("img", {"data-veloute":"map/GoogleMapStatic"})).attrs['src']
    parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    print(parse_qs(parsed.query)['center'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
['53.8147,-1.52538']
```

Comment: I'm getting ```AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'```

Comment: @TeaTree Yeah, that's because airbnb made some changes to their website & the exact location isn't available anymore.

Answer (score 4):

They are present in a script tag. You can regex from response text without resorting to overhead of a browser.

```
import requests, re

r = requests.get('https://www.airbnb.co.uk/rooms/15307317')
p_lat = re.compile(r'"lat":([-0-9.]+),')
p_lng = re.compile(r'"lng":([-0-9.]+),')
lat = p_lat.findall(r.text)[0]
lng = p_lng.findall(r.text)[0]
print(lat,lng)
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the `response` to a file and see what the page really looks like. Most of the contents are loaded dynamically. You'll need a browser to handle javascript dynamic content loading.

[selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) or [pyppeteer](https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer) are the most popular browser scripting libs.